# cookie base64_decode not working correctly

Tags: php, cookies

Im trying to set a cookie when the user selects the checkbox to remember his data.
I´m setting cookie and encoding if checkbox is selected:

```
if($f['save'])
{
$cookiesave = base64_encode($adminEmail).'&'.base64_encode($f['pass']);
setcookie('admin',$cookiesave,time()+60*60*24*30,'/');         
}
```

And then I´m decoding

```
elseif(!empty($_COOKIE['admin']))
            {
                $cookie = $_COOKIE['admin'];
                $cookie = explode('&',$cookie);
                $f['email'] = base64_decode($cookie[0]);
                $f['pass'] = base64_decode($cookie[1]);
                $f['save'] = 1;
            }
```

But despite being doing the decode, the input appears with encrypted password.
I have reviewed all the code and everything seems to be right ... can see anything wrong?

My full code:

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['sendLogin']))
         {
            $f['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $f['pass']  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
            $f['save']  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['remember']);

                $autEmail = $f['email'];
                $autSenha = md5($f['pass']);
                $readAdmin = read('admins',"WHERE email = '$adminEmail'");
                if($readADmin){
                    foreach($readAdmin as $admin);
                    if($adminEmail == $admin['email'] && $adminPass == $admin['pass'])
                    {
                        if($f['save'])
                        {
                            $cookiesave = base64_encode($adminEmail).'&'.base64_encode($f['pass']);
                            setcookie('admin',$cookiesave,time()+60*60*24*30,'/');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            setcookie('admin','',time()+3600,'/');
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Wrong Password';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Email dont exist in DB';
                }
            }

        }
        elseif(!empty($_COOKIE['admin']))
        {
            $cookie = $_COOKIE['admin'];
            $cookie = explode('&',$cookie);
            $f['email'] = base64_decode($cookie[0]);
            $f['pass'] = base64_decode($cookie[1]);
            $f['save'] = 1;
        }
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($cookie);
            echo
               '</pre>';
    ?>

        <?php
        if(!isset($_GET['remember']))
        {
        ?>
        <form name="login" action="" method="post">
            <label>
                <span>Email:</span>
                <input type="text" class="radius" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($f['email'])) echo $f['email']; ?>" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Password:</span>
                <input type="password" class="radius" name="pass" value="<?php if(isset($f['pass'])) echo $f['pass']; ?>" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sendLogin" class="btn" />

            <div class="remember">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" <?php if(isset($f['save'])) echo 'checked="checked"' ?> /> 
                Remember Acess data!
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
        }
```

Comment: the whole point of base64_encoding is that you can be certain the the string is 'html' safe. You can pass it around anywhere in 'html' land and it will be unchanged.You then make it 'html unsafe' by sticking an '&' in it.

Comment: Don't save the plain text password in cookie X_X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tested login form (PHP 5.3.18). The comments at the start of the script explains how it works and how to use it.

```
<?php
/*
 * Q22459571
 *
 * a Login script:
 *
 * There are three actions it will do:
 *
 * 1) Display a login screen and process the results
 *
 * 2) Logout a user who has been 'remembered' or 'saved' see 'admin' cookie.
 *
 * 3) Automatically login a user from the details in the admin' cookie.
 *
 * The script action is controlled by a parameter in the URL called 'action'.
 *
 * The 'action' values and results are as follows:
 *
 * 1) action='login'   : will clear any cookies and force the login screen to be shown
 *
 * 2) action='logout'  : will clear any cookies and exit the script
 *
 * 3) missing 'action' parameter : a) try and login using the 'admin' cookie.
 *                                 b) show the login screen if not
 *                                    able to login.
 *
 * The result of the script will be saved in a '$userAuth' array as follows:
 *
 * 1) 'email'       => user email address as stored on the db.
 * 2) 'passhash'    => MD5 hash as stored on the database
 * 3) 'remember'    => boolean to indicate that the user can be logged in
 *                     via the 'admin' cookie
 * 4) 'loginMethod' => '', 'cookie', 'form'
 * 5) 'loginSuccess'=> true | false
 *
 */

/*
 * We will use 'mysqli' functions, prepared queries and 'bind' variables/values
 */

/*
 * User table:
 *
 * store password as a 'salted' hash
 *
 * Columns: 1) email    -- unique id for an admin
 *          2) passhash -- password as a MD5 hash
 *          3) salt     -- random string that we will use as a prefix to the plaintext password
 *                         before we take the md5 hash.
 */

// database connection...
$mysqlDb = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'testmysql');

// User Authorization details will always be in here...
$userAuth = array( 'email' => '', 'passhash' => '', 'remember' => false,
                   'loginMethod' => '', 'loginSuccess' => false);

// set the login action so we can use it later
$loginAction = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';

/*
 * see what the URL action is
 */
if ($loginAction == 'logout')
{
  setcookie('admin', '' , 0, '/'); // delete cookie
  echo 'user logged out';          // do what you wish here
  exit;                            // leave the script
}


if ($loginAction == 'login')
{
  if (!empty($_COOKIE['admin'])) // clear the cookie to force login
  {
    setcookie('admin', '' , time() + 3600, '/'); // will be empty next time
  }
}
elseif (!empty($_COOKIE['admin'])) // The cookie should be encrypted -- not in this version.
{
   $cookie = $_COOKIE['admin'];
   $emailLen = substr($cookie, 0, 3); // get the length

   $b64 = substr($cookie, 3); // get b64 encoded string
   $b64decoded = base64_decode($b64); // convert back to original string

    // split it up...
   $userAuth['email'] = substr($b64decoded, 0, $emailLen);
   $userAuth['passhash']  = substr($b64decoded, $emailLen);
   $userAuth['remember' ]  = 1;


   // ensure user is in the database and the details match...
   $sql = 'SELECT email, salt from admins WHERE email = ? and passhash = ? limit 1';
   $query = mysqli_prepare($mysqlDb, $sql);
   $allOk = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'ss', $userAuth['email'], $userAuth['passhash']);
   $allOk = mysqli_execute($query);
   $queryResult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($query);
   $admin = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult);

   $userAuth['loginMethod'] = 'cookie';
   $userAuth['loginSuccess'] =    !empty($admin['email'])
                               && $admin['email'] === $userAuth['email'];


   if ($userAuth['loginSuccess'])
   {
      echo 'user: ', $userAuth['email'], ' was logged in via the cookie...';
      exit;
   }
   else
   {
      echo 'user: ', $userAuth['email'], ' cookie details are wrong!!';
      exit;
   }
}


/*
 * We may have a login request that we need to check...
 */
 if (isset($_POST['sendLogin'])) // new login attempt
 {
   $userAuth['loginMethod'] = 'form';
   $userAuth['loginSuccess'] = false;

   $userAuth['email']     = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqlDb, $_POST['email']);
   $userPass              = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqlDb, $_POST['pass']);
   $userAuth['remember']  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqlDb, $_POST['remember']);



    // will use prepared queries and bind parameters as required
    $sql = 'SELECT email, passhash, salt from admins WHERE email = ? limit 1';
    $query = mysqli_prepare($mysqlDb, $sql);
    $allOk = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 's', $userAuth['email']);
    $allOk = mysqli_execute($query);

    $queryResult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($query);
    $admin = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult); // admin details

    if (   !empty($userAuth['email']) && $userAuth['email'] == $admin['email']
        && !empty($userPass))
    {
      // calculate the MD5 hash and assume it is ok
      $userAuth['passhash'] = md5($admin['salt'] . $userPass);
    }


    if (!empty($userAuth['passhash']) && $userAuth['passhash'] === $admin['passhash']) // passwords must have matched
    {
        $userAuth['loginSuccess'] = true;
        if ($userAuth['remember' ])
        {
           $emailLen = sprintf('%03u', strlen($userAuth['email']));
           $cookiesave = $emailLen . base64_encode($userAuth['email'] . $userAuth['passhash']);
           setcookie('admin', $cookiesave, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/');
        }
        else
        {
           setcookie('admin', '' , 0, '/'); // delete cookie
        }
    }
    else
    {
        setcookie('admin', '' , 0, '/'); // delete cookie if unsuccessful login
        echo 'Wrong Email / Password or both';
    }
 } // end of form login

// if successful login
if ($userAuth['loginSuccess'])
{
  echo 'user: ', $userAuth['email'], ' is  logged in via: ', $userAuth['loginMethod'];
  exit;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Enter Login Details</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form name="login" action="/testmysql/Q22459571_cookie_base64.php
        " method="post">
      <label>
          <span>Email:</span>
          <input type="text" class="radius" name="email" value="<?php echo $userAuth['email']; ?>" />
      </label>
      <label>
          <span>Password:</span>
          <input type="password" class="radius" name="pass" value="" />
      </label>

      <div class="remember">
          <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" value="1" <?php echo 'checked="checked"' ?> />
          <label  for="remember">Remember Me!</label>
      </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Login"  name="sendLogin" class="btn" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```